# Can you use cooking oil to make "African Drop Doughnuts"?

Tags: oil, doughnuts, african

Do you have to use deep-fry oil or corn oil to make "African Drop Doughnuts" or can you use cooking oil?

Comment: I don't know them, but going by the pictures I found, any (vegetable) oil suitable for deep frying (i.e. canola, sunflower, peanut, etc.) will do.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I've made it and it looks like it worked 

Comment: Dee7, as you are new to the site, please visit our help center, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help. to learn the best ways to ask and answer questions. I am flagging your answer below as that should not have been entered as an answer, but instead as a comment. Hope to see you around more!

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Since the OP has tried your suggestion and it worked, I would suggest that you expand on your comment a little and enter it as an answer. :)

Comment: For some values of "cooking oil", "corn oil" and "cooking oil" are exact synonyms. In other words, there's no one oil type that is called "cooking oil". Ditto for "deep-fry oil", for that matter: you can certainly deep-fry in corn oil, which would then make those two terms synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a specific answer since I don't know what temperature you need. I looked at a couple recipes for African Drop Donuts and the temperatures were pretty far apart: 340F and 375F. I also don't know what you mean by cooking oil!

But you can use any oil suitable for deep-frying at the temperature specified in the recipe. Depending on what kind of cooking oil you have it may be fine, or it might have too low a smoke point.

Things like canola, sunflower, peanut, corn, and safflower would most likely be fine, since they all have smoke points of 400F or higher and are pretty neutral. You can look at a [table of smoke points](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Information/CookingOilTypes.htm) to get an idea beyond that.

The one thing you probably want to be careful about is oil labeled as generic vegetable oil; without knowing what kind of oil it actually is, it's hard to know what its smoke point is. It might also be more strongly flavored.